# How to enable the other form control when new screen show

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I working on a vb.net form, when a new screen pop up, all the parent control is disable. All the parent form control will work, When you closed the pop screen.
How do I let the parent control work when the new screen pop up.

Comment: Use `Form.Show` instead of `Form.ShowDialog`?

Comment: I'm using Form.Show, but parent control still not working

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifyable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As MatSnow commented, use Form.Show in your original code, but after that try adding `Me.Focus()` this should put focus back on the parent form.